# mount.exfat-fuse mounts drive r/o

Tags: mount, exfat

I'm mounting an external exFat drive on a rooted Android device (Amazon Fire TV/2) using the mount.exfat-fuse program.

```
mount.exfat-fuse -o rw,umask=000 /dev/block/sda1 /system/test
```

directory permissions are 777, but permission denied for anything root tries.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `/system` is read-only by default, could be related.  It's certainly not a good place to be mounting external drives.

Comment: system was mounted r/w and the location was just for easy testing of a script in xbin, but thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that SELinux policy on the Amazon Fire TV/2 caused my exFat drive to be read-only when mounted, despite mounting arguments. The SELinux command setenforce can be run with an argument of 0 or 1, setting SELinux to permissive or enforced, respectively. When set to 0, the drive can be used normally.

So, I check for the presence of setenforce in my mount script and set it to 0 if found. The unmounting script does setenforce 1, putting things back as they were.

Comment: can you please post a more detailed answer ,so it can be useful as a future reference :) thanks in advance

Comment: Sure. I hope this helps someone else.